# The Higgs potential

Tags: quantum-field-theory, standard-model, higgs

I am studying the Higgs mechanism and I see there are only quadratic/mass and quartic terms in the Higgs potential. Why aren't there for example linear and cubic terms as well?
Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Why *should* there be such terms? It's not clear to me what you're asking for here - Lagrangians/potentials can in principle be anything you want, and it turns out that this particular potential produces a Higgs mechanism.

Answer (score 3):

**Why not odd potential terms**

Potentials that are odd in the field $\phi$ would give you an unstable field theory, one that will never reach or live nearby an equilibrium position.

Same as having a ball in a potential $mgh$, where it would just keep rolling downwards. Hence potentials with minma, like $mx^2$, are interesting, because you can live near that point and exhibit "stable" dynamics and orbits.

**Why not even potential powers > 4**

Look at renormalisation, there is an argument for which a theory with $O(\phi^6)$ terms is not renormalisable.

**Why not odd kinetic terms**

You could also ask why aren't there any odd power of the *gradients* of the field, like $\propto(\nabla\phi)$ or $\propto(\nabla\phi)^3$ etc. 
 Gradients are associated with momentum, since $\hat{p} \leftrightarrow \frac{\hbar}{i}\nabla$. 
 The "kinetic energy" term of the Lagrangians and Hamiltonians usually has the form $\propto p^2$, hence the appearing of terms $\propto \partial^{\mu}\phi\,\partial_{\mu}\phi \propto (\nabla \phi)^2$. 
 Having a term that goes with an odd power of the momentum would imply can take energy from negative momentum modes and create new positive momentum modes. 
 Like, you start with no modes, and you end up with one at $|+p\rangle$ and one at $|-p\rangle$. Energy is conserved since it goes as $\propto p.$

**Why not even kinetic powers > 2**

But then why not having something that goes as $\propto p^4 \propto (\nabla \phi)^4$? 
 This actually I do not know, but I assume, by Occam's razor, the lower power terms worked as well (if not better) so there was no need to extend it futher. 
 But I am not entirely sure, maybe someone else can confirm this.

---

**What's special about the Higgs**

What's amazing about the Higgs potential is that there is really nothing special about it, mathematically. 
 Once you accept all of the above constraints, or at least the ones about the potential terms $\propto \phi^n$, you see can you can only have $\phi^2$ and $\phi^4$ terms. 
 The only "freedom" you are left is the *sign* of these terms... which is why you make up a tachyonic mass term (one with the "wrong" sign) and see what happens.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks. Is there any more fundamental reasons like Lorentz invariance for example if it were a vector field?

Comment: That is a good question. Not that I am aware of, a spin-1/2 or spin-1 theory would need to obey the same functional constraints I said above. I think. I cannot think of a reason of the action/Lagrangian being Lorentz invariant apart from the fact that the E-L equations need to be valid in all frames. Lorentz invariance is enforced by having no free indices, like $F^{\mu \nu} F_{\mu \nu}$.

Answer (score 2):

The potential doesn't include odd order terms because a key feature of the Higgs mechanism is that the physical laws don't break the symmetry, the state of the universe does. Thus, the Higgs potential, kinetic terms, and interactions need to be invariant under the gauge symmetry transformation that it was put in to help "dynamically" break. Adding odd powers would violate the desired symmetry in the Lagrangian, making the gauge symmetry explicitly broken instead of dynamically. I've never seen the details, but it's my understanding that this does very bad things to how gauge theories behave (consistency? anomalies?).

Because of these concerns, it's really better to think of the potential as being a function of $\phi^\dagger\phi$ than as a function of $\phi$.

That said, @SuperCiocia is correct about odd powers in the sense that having them be the highest power in the theory would make it unstable in a way that is unphysical. If there weren't the requirement for the Higgs field to obey a gauge symmetry, or even just a global symmetry, then odd terms of lower order than the highest order even term would be fine, though, because the high order even term will keep the field strength confined to finite values.